# Handling batch file through loadrunner

Tags: c, batch-file, command-prompt, performance-testing, vugen

I have a batch file creating the Signature which eventually triggers a jar file and I am passing some keys (user inputs) to the batch file, 3 values one by one e.g. Key, timestamp, and the token. The vugen script is able to open the batch file but now it is asking me some inputs to enter.

Can anyone suggest how can I pass these value from vugen?

Comment: You should show the code that isn't working

Comment: I asked this question to my crystal ball and it told me that the problem is in line # 7 of the vugen script... **`;)`**

Comment: Actually i will not be able to share the code as this is private. Can someone tell me how can i pass parameters from Loadrunner to batch file so that i can use the same in batch file. I tried using the System(), but here i can only pass the command not the arguments

Comment: If you can't provide some type of code that produces the same type of execution then we cannot help you and your question will be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered a Java virtual user with your Java Code from your JAR file instead of being invoked from a batch file.....which will not wait for your call to complete before executing the next statement.